# Getting Floating Objects via Office-js

Tags: office-js, officedev

**Background**
I've been working on an addin which inserts inline pictures but when a user changes the layout of the image to any of the floating layouts it becomes essentially invisible to Office js.

**Question**
Is it possible to get floating objects from the document via Office-js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inline and floating shapes are 2 different objects from the Word programmability perspective (and the file format itself). so the fact that a user transforms a picture from inline to floating has the immediate effect of not been part of the inlinePictures collection.

This will be mitigated in the future by adding floating images/shapes functionalities in the API.

Comment: Are you in a position to share an ETA of those functionalities as they would be extremely helpful for my use case